# Derivation provides Complement

Tags: group-theory

Let  $G = N \rtimes H$ be a semidirect product of subgroup $H$ and and a normal subgroup $N$. We know that the complement $X$ to $N$ (therefore a subgroup $X$ such that $G = XN$ and $X \cap N = 1$) isn't unique.

I read that a ***derivation*** $\delta: H \to N$ (therefore a map such that the rule
$$(h_1h2)^{\delta}= (h_1^{\delta})^{h_2}h_2^{\delta}$$ holds) provides via $X_{\delta}:= \{hh^{\delta} \vert h \in H\}$ a complements.

Obviously $G= X_{\delta}N$ holds

but I don't see how to prove $X_{\delta} \cap N = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That follows immediately from the definition of $X_\delta$. Since $h^\delta \in N$, and $H \cap N = 1$, the only element of $X_\delta$ that could lie in $N$ is $11^\delta$ but any derivation satisfies $1^\delta = 1$.